# Does anyone know how to get the `InsertItem` of detail table of radgrid?

Tags: radgrid, telerik-grid

Does anyone know how to get the `InsertItem` of detail table of radgrid?
I can get from master table using the following code.

```
Radgrid1.MasterTableView.GetInsertItem();
```

But how can I get it  from detailtable?

Answer (score 1):

You need the index of the parent item:

`RadGrid1.Items[?].ChildItem.NestedTableViews[0].GetInsertItem();`

In a EventHandler you can iterate through the parent objects of the sender until the GridEditFormInsertItem.